# What was the outcome of the meeting between humans and Zygons in "The Day of the Doctor"?

Tags: doctor-who, the-day-of-the-doctor

Does anyone have any idea what was the result of the negotiations between humans and Zygons in the 50th anniversary special? Doctors 10 and 11 left to reunite with the War Doctor and The Moment, but then the special ended and no one really knows what happened. I'm assuming they somehow worked out a peace between the species, but this was not really shown within the episode. Is it shown anywhere else?

**EDIT:**
When this question was asked (Dec. '13). "The day of the doctor" was the last episode that had aired.

Comment: They worked it all out nicely, and [everyone lived happily ever after](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Zygon_Invasion).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question is in need of an updated answer, after the airing of Series 9 last year.

---

In the two-parter story comprising episodes 7 and 8, "The Zygon Invasion" and "The Zygon Inversion", we learn that the treaty drawn up by the humans and Zygons involved

> twenty million Zygons rehabilitated on Earth, taking the form of humans and living unobtrusively among us. The twin Osgoods, one human and one Zygon, were the maintainers and symbols of the peace, which was also ensured by the Osgood Boxes, one red and one blue.

This much we know at the very start of "The Zygon Invasion", from the message recorded by the two Osgoods at the time the treaty was made:

> OSGOOD 1: Operation Double is a covert operation, outside of normal UNIT strictures, to resettle and rehouse an alien race in secrecy on planet Earth.
>   OSGOOD 2:  With UNIT's help, twenty million Zygons have been allowed to take human form, been dispersed around the world, and are now living amongst us.
>   OSGOOD 1: We're making this in case something goes wrong. In case UNIT is infiltrated. In case something occurs to unmask the Zygons.

When the peace breaks down and the Doctor is called back (the "Nightmare Scenario"), we also learn what the Osgood boxes do:

> there are two buttons in each box. Supposedly, one of these buttons would save, and the other would destroy, each of the humans and Zygons. But it transpires at the very end of the episode, after the Doctor does his awesome speech, that in fact both boxes are empty, and the point of the whole thing is to make both sides understand what war is all about and that what they should really do is "Sit! Down! And talk!"

As the Doctor explains:

> DOCTOR: One of those buttons will destroy the Zygons, release the imbecile's gas. The other one detonates the nuclear warhead under the Black Archive. It'll destroy everyone in London. Bonnie. Bonnie, sweetheart! One of those buttons will unmask every Zygon in the world. The other one cancels their ability to change form. It'll make them human beings for ever. There are safeguards beyond safeguards. I did this on a very important day for me and this ceasefire will stand.

Comment: Somewhat ironic, isn't it, that the quoted text reveals 99% of what's hidden behind the spoiler tag above it? :)

Answer (score 6):

I saw this on [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/gallifrey/comments/1vuozl/steven_moffat_doctor_who_magazine_qa_feb_2014/):

> Each month Steven Moffat writes a column at the beginning of Doctor
>   Who Magazine. Usually (but not always) these take the form of answers
>   to questions sent in by readers.

One such questions:

> What do you imagine the deal struck between UNIT and the Zygons while
>   under 'the veil of Ignorance', when neither was able to remember which
>   of them was which, would have actually entailed? Would it mean that
>   the entire Zygon race is now living among us in human form, perhaps so
>   long as they refrain from reverting to looking like 'big red rubbery
>   things covered in suckers'? If so, wouldn't the sudden leap in Earth's
>   population attract attention?

And Moffat's response was:

> In the original script, there was an exchange something like this:
>
> ---
>
> ***THE DOCTOR:** There's enough technology in this very room to get Zygons safely off world.*
>
> ***KATE:** So they can destroy us from space?*
>
> ***THE DOCTOR:** They won't. Because there will be safeguards - you're about to agree on them.*
>
> ---
>
> All that fell victim to the final push because (a) it actually felt a
>   bit clumsy, and (b) I quite liked the idea that we don't know what
>   they negotiated. Maybe they agreed on shift-work identities for human
>   beings - life shares for selected humans and Zygons. I thought, maybe
>   wrongly, that it was obvious the Doctor's solution would work, but I
>   rather liked that we'd all have to speculate what the solution was. If
>   any species could move in with us, discreetly, it would be the Zygons.
>   What deal was reached in the tower of London, that allowed
>   shapeshifters to walk among us? And what might happen in the future?
>   It's a typical Doctor solution, isn't it? Brilliant, chaotic,
>   optimistic - and what the hell happens next!? Think about it - what
>   would you agree to, if you didn't know which side you were on? (Well
>   done on 'veil of ignorance', by the way - let's make everybody look it
>   up.)

Answer (score 2):

### Not yet known.

The Doctors were confident that the negotiations would all work out for the best, but we weren't actually shown or told anything conclusive about the outcome

However: the last scene of the negotiation has Osgood and Osgood's double figuring out which is a Zygon because we know only Real Osgood had an inhaler (she picked it up from her unconscious double in an earlier scene). This implies that the enforced ignorance backing up the productive negotiation might be about to fail--and we can only speculate how their brief moment of forced empathy will influence them once it falls away.

Comment: it also implies that maybe not all of the Zygons are anxious to take over Earth, as "Osgon" doesn't immediately our herself or her human partner. (Not that I know what good it would have done with the pair-o-Kates still not knowing which was which.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there was anywhere where it was shown that there was a truce, but it is certainly implied that there was one because nobody knew whether or not they were Zygon or human.  In fact I believe the Osgood was talking in a polite manner with her copy.  They most likely came to some sort of peaceful negotiation because there was no nuclear explosion at the end, and the Black Archive was still standing.